# Web application manage uploaded document

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am making file attach web application.

**My Question :**
When i attach file upload on click attach button, so i have no idea where i put this attach file?

I am finding solution for this question in google. so i find two ways, either using file system or save attach file in database. I am using file system way.

in my application, dynamically create "upload" folder and put this attach file.

ex. if "upload" folder is not exists then create new "upload" folder in particular path and put this attach file and if "upload" folder is already exists so put this attach file in this folder.

however when i make build for my web application, at that time this "upload" folder becomes delete and lost my all attach file. so any other way, how can i manage uploaded document?

please guide me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storing data into the Filesystem doesn't mean you have to use your project Directory,
Store your data in your computer e.g. `C:/storedFiles`, so you can keep your data after building your web Application.

Make sure that you are keeping your Filesystem data and the database in **SYNC**, you can do that by checking that the database reference is deleted before deleting a file from the filesystem.

Unfortunately, you will end up having some extra **UNUSED** files in the filesystem that aren't referenced in the database, that's why you should implement a **nighty batch process** to collect and delete non-referenced files since they're unusable.

## Edit :

If you want to access something like that : `example.com/download/abc.png`. you will need to create a controller with something like this :

```
@RequestMapping(value="/download/{imageUrl:.+}")
public void getImageByUrl(@PathVariable String imageUrl, 
HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException 
{
    /*
     * Getting The Content From The Images Folder in The Storage Directory
     * Creating an Input Stream and Passing it to The View
     */
    String filesFolder = /* Here goes you storage Folder */;
    File someImage= new File(filesFolder+"/"+imageUrl);
    FileInputStream fileStream=new FileInputStream(someImage);       

            try {
                response.getOutputStream().write(IOUtils.toByteArray(fileStream));
                response.getOutputStream().flush();
                response.getOutputStream().close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: If i create folder in `*C*` drive then while downloding from application will not work. So i have to create it within web app which can be access via web application. Isn't it?

Comment: No, create a *.properties* file where you store your storage path, when you want to download an Image for example, you may obviously have its name from the database, and you already have your path from the properties file, so there's nothing holding you back from downloading your file normally.

Comment: What i mean is, if i want to redirect an user to abc.png image then what i do right now is, http://example.com/upload/abc.png ..... If i move attachment to c drive i won't be able to access it like this